# How to get data from current logged user

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase User data]

After running the app it shows another user name instead of the loggged user...

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            // To get children count
            dataSnapshot.getChildren();

           // email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
         //   gender = dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString();

            name = dataSnapshot.child("Nome").getValue().toString();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the userId when retrieving the data, to be able to retrieve the data of the currently logged in user.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId = user.getUid();
```

Then you can do:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Condutores").child(userId);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("Database", dataSnapshot.child("Nome").getValue(String.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
})
```

Add a reference to the node `userId`, then attach a `ValueEventListener` and retrieve the data of the user.